# How to understand "something agrees with someone"?

Tags: meaning

I was watching Friends S01E05. There is a piece of conversation i cannot understand very clearly - Monica Says,"Being dumped by you obviously agrees with her." Shouldn't it be "someone agree with something"? Can we say "something agrees with someone"? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying something agrees with someone means that the person is improved by [doing] that thing.
 In your quote the story is that prior to being dumped, the person was apparently not very happy but after being dumped the must have been a remarkable improvement in their disposition.
Likewise when something doesn’t agree with someone that thing does harm to the person.   A person who says that Lima beans doesn’t agree with them may feel sick when they eat them.